# Struts 2 select readonly property

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I have a situation where I need to make `<s:select>` drop down value to read only. But since the `<s:select>` only has disabled property, how to make `<s:select>` behave read only. I have directly put `readonly` on `<s:select>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Readonly on `<s:select>`? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why `disabled="true"` is not valid for what you want? It's the way I did it when I needed it.

Comment: Disabled form items aren't sent to the browser. Either keep the value in a hidden field as well, or code the back end so the value isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like putting a HTML attribute `contenteditable="true"` makes it to behave like readonly. That a way you couldn't select the value from dropdown.

Comment: Please tell me is this working for chrome or internet explorer because it is not working for me plz help me

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it Write some CSS, and then just put a HTML attribute `readonly="true"`**

```
 /*Select2 ReadOnly Start*/
    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container {
        pointer-events: none;
        touch-action: none;
    }
    
    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection {
        background: #eee;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection__arrow, select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container .select2-selection__clear {
        display: none;
    }
    
    /*Select2 ReadOnly End*/
```