# how to make Struts2 select tag readonly

Tags: java, select, struts2, readonly

I want my `<s:select>` to be readonly, I don't want it to be disabled because I have to submit the value of `<s:select>` to my action class.

Here is other question related to this ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17373292/2764279)), but the answer given has not worked here.

Is there any way to readonly my `<s:select>`, how can I achieve this???

Comment: If it's going to be readonly, why do you use a select?

Comment: I selected it when my page load 1st time, and want to make it readonly with previous selected value when the page load 2nd time.@Andres

Comment: Disable + hidden field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `<s:select>` tag `disabled` and have a *hidden field having its name and value*. so, that it can be sent in the request to the server for processing.

Comment: How can I select value to hidden field?

Comment: How can you disable it but not making it pale? I mean, to have the same look like the other properties but without being able to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Keerthivasan

Example

```
<s:select value="aaa" id="source_id" listValue="name" disabled="true" />
<s:hidden name="destination_name" />


$('input[name="destination_name"]').val(
    $("#source_id option:selected").val()
);
```